# How do I view the PDF file downloaded from docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am downloading the signed documents using the docusign getDocument API, but the downloaded file is coming in a weird format(json as per the Content-type header). What format is this and how can I convert it to a viewable/readable format.

Here is a snippet from the response -

%PDF-1.5\n%ûüýþ\n%Writing objects...\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Page\n/Resources 5 0 R\n/Parent 3 0 R\n/MediaBox [0 0 595.32000 841.92000 ]\n/Contents [6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R ]\n/Group <<\n/Type /Group\n/S /Transparency\n/CS /DeviceRGB\n>>\n/Tabs /S\n/StructParents 0\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<<\n/Font <<\n/F1 9 0 R\n/F2 10 0 R\n/F3 11 0 R\n/F4 12 0 R\n/F5 13 0 R\n>>\n/ExtGState <<\n/GS7 14 0 R\n/GS8 15 0 R\n>>\n/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]\n/XObject <<\n/X0 16 0 R\n>>\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (PDFKit.NET 21.1.200.20790)\n/CreationDate (D:20210429103256-07'00')\n/ModDate (D:20210429103256-07'00')\n/Author ()\n/Creator ()\n/Keywords <>\n/Subject ()\n/Title ()\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/Length 4\n>>\nstream\n\n q \nendstream\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<<\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 7326\n>>\nstream\nxœ½]ëo\u001c7’ÿnÀÿCã\u0016¸›YDm¾šd\u0007A\u0000É’\u001dçüZ[Þà\u0010ï\u0007Å’ma-É‘FÉæ¿?

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippit, but it looks like that may be a PDF. If you dump the response into a file and try to open it with a PDF viewer, does it work?

Comment: @Drew If I save it as .pdf and try to open it, I get file is damaged. I also tried saving it as an HTML file, but it just displays the same content as in the snippet.

Comment: @Ishita did you solve the problem. If so please let me know. I too have the same problem.

Comment: @PrabhuChaitanyavarma I added a callback function in the getDocument call. You can check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this piece of code to save the response from DocuSign getDocument API to a PDF document-

```
envelopesApi.getDocument(ACCOUNT_ID, envelope_id, 'combined', function (error, document, response) {
if (document) {
  var filename = ‘docusign.pdf';
  fs.writeFile(filename, new Buffer(document, 'binary'), function (err) {
    if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err);
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using, and are you using one of the DocuSign SDKs or a raw API call?

When I make a GetDocument call (specifically `{{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/combined`, for example), the response headers have `Content-Type: application/pdf` and `Content-Dispostion: file; filename=file.pdf`, and the body of the response is the binary of the PDF file itself.

A snippet of mine begins with this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%����
%Writing objects...
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources 10 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792 ]
/Contents [11 0 R 12 0 R 13 0 R 14 0 R 15 0 R 16 0 R 17 0 R ]
/Group <<
/Type /Group
/S /Transparency
/CS /DeviceRGB
```

So it looks like whatever system you have picking up the response is including `\n` newlines and potentially other control characters.

You'll want to look at how your tools handle the API response: if you can dump the raw output from DocuSign to a PDF file, that would work, but with the extra formatting being injected it's no longer valid.

Comment: I'm using the DocuSign SDK in nodeJS and this is the response I got on postman. Content type is also application/json; charset=utf-8. But thanks, I'll try to fix the formatting .